# AJAX Masked Textbox custom mask

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a slider on my page and I want to set it up so that when the user slides (which is in minutes) it displays a 'pretty' version of the current selection. So, for example, if the slider is on '60' then it would display '1 hour' and if it is on '65' it would display '1 hour and 5 minutes'

What is the best approach? If it is a custom mask on the MaskedEditExtender control then how would I achieve this? I wrote code behind on c# but I don't want it to change when the mouse is let go, but rather as the slider itself is moving.

Hopefully I am making sense! Thanks in advance. :)

Here is the current slider:

```
        <div class="controlColumn">                    
            <asp:TextBox  ID="Slider1"  runat="server" Width="400px"  AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender runat="server" ID="sPrepTime" Minimum="0" Maximum="1440" Decimals="0" Steps="288" TargetControlID="Slider1" BoundControlID="Slider1_BoundControl" Orientation="Horizontal"></ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender>
            <asp:TextBox  ID="Slider1_BoundControl"  runat="server" Width="100px" OnTextChanged="Slider1_BoundControl_TextChanged" TextMode="Number" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPrepTime" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
```

OnTextChanged triggers once the mouse has stopped selecting the slider.

**UPDATE**

I was not able to make what i needed work with the AJAX slider but moved to the Jquery UI slider using the javascript that was provided below. My jquery code is:

```
$(function() {       
    $( "#slider" ).slider({            
        value:0,            
        min: 0,            
        max: 1440,            
        step: 5,            
        slide: function( event, ui ) {                
            $("#MainContent_amount2").val(ui.value);
            $('#MainContent_lblPrepTime').text(minutesToText(ui.value));

        }        
    });        
    $("#MainContent_amount2").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
});
```

You can find more information on the Jquery UI here: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#default

Comment: what slider is being used? Post code currently used to display values

Comment: @charlietfl - I added the code requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can provide you with javascript number to text parsing code

```
function minutesToText(val) {
    var hours = parseInt(val / 60,10),
        minutes, hourText = '',
        minuteText = '';
    if(hours >= 1) {
        minutes = val - (hours * 60);
        hourText = hours + ' hour' + pluralize(hours)+', '

    } else {
        minutes = val;
    }
    minuteText = minutes+ ' minute' + pluralize(minutes);
    return hourText + minuteText;
}

function pluralize(num) {
    return num == 1 ? '' : 's'
}
```

I am not very familiar with ajaxToolkit so I am not sure how asp.Net would register this custom method. If using manual code to initialize would be fairly straighforward

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4UBJM/2/

Comment: Thank you for this! I ended up using this along with the jquery ui slider that can be found here: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps. I'll add my code to my original post for future users.

Comment: OK  very easy to use `slide` option of jQuery UI slider and this function

Comment: made minor update..forgot `radix` argument for `parseInt` method